# Função para buscar caracter

Tags: funções, char, java-processing

Estou tentando escrever uma função que retorna o index do caracter.
Por exemplo, quero buscar o index de 'a' a quinta vez que ele aparece no texto.

Esse é o meu código:

```
int buscaChar (String text, char c, int n) {
  int index=0;
  int count=0;
  for (int i=0; i<text.length()-1; i++) {
    if (text.charAt(i)==c)
    count=count+1;  
    if(count==n) 
    index= i;
  }
  return index;
}
```

Chamada da função:

```
String textCopy = "A linguagem processing e a mais divertida.";

  test=buscaChar(textCopy, 'a', 1); 

 println(test);
```

Deveria imprimir 40, mas retorna o index incorreto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que o seu primeiro `if` não abrange o segundo.

Da forma que está (indentando corretamente):

```
for (int i=0; i<text.length()-1; i++) {
    if (text.charAt(i)==c)
        count=count+1;  
    if(count==n)
        index= i;
}
```

Vai fazer com que o `if(count==n)` seja executado, independentemente quer esteja ou não na letra certa.

Imaginando a buscar para a letra `a` e `n` a `1` começa por:

- Apanhar o primeiro `a` da `String` na posição `7`
- Alterar `count` para `1`
- Atualizar o `index` porque `count` é igual a `n`
- A próxima letra ja não é `a` mas o `count` continua a `1`, logo volta a atualizar o `index` para `8` erradamente. Irá continuar a atualizar para as letras seguintes, até que o `count` volte a aumentar ou a `String` termine.

Resolve isto facilmente com `{}`, incluindo o segundo `if` no primeiro:

```
for (int i = 0; i < text.length() - 1; i++) {
    if (text.charAt(i) == c) { //abre aqui
        count = count + 1;
        if (count == n)
            index = i;
    } //fecha aqui incluindo o outro if
}
```

Assim apenas quando as letras são iguais existe possibilidade de atualização do `index`.

Uma vez encontrada a posição deixa de ser util fazer qualquer outro processamento. Por este motivo pode melhorar ainda o método movendo o retorno diretamente para dentro do `if`:

```
int buscaChar(String text, char c, int n) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (text.charAt(i) == c) {
            count = count + 1;
            if (count == n)
                return i; //apenas return
        }
    }
    return -1; //retorna -1 quando não existe
}
```

Desta forma o seu código não só não faz processamento desnecessário, como fica até mais simples.

Repare também como troquei o valor de retorno quando não existe para `-1`, que é um valor universal para este tipo de funções. Esta troca dos returns fez com que a variável `index` nem sequer fosse necessária.

[Veja este código a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/eKhykI)

Note que para ter os `40` que indicou tem de ser o 4º `a` e não o 5º pois o primeiro é maiúsculo e por isso não conta.

Comment: Valeu! Agora funcionou!